# How to run Google Chrome in AWS Lambda for Selenium tests using Java + ChromeDriver

Tags: java, selenium, aws-lambda, selenium-chromedriver, headless

I use the following versions:

- Selenium - 3.14.0
- Webdrivermanager - 2.2.4

To create ChromeDriver I use the following configuration:

```
WebDriverManager.chromedriver()
            .targetPath("/tmp")
            .setup();

    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("--headless", "--no-sandbox", "--disable-dev-shm-usage");
    options.setBinary("/tmp");

    ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

When I run my lambda the following exception occurs(from lambda logs):

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
(The process started from chrome location /tmp is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

Is there a good way to install Chrome browser in AWS Lambda and provide it for ChromeDriver?

Comment: Did you ever happen to get this working?   I am fighting the same issue except from C#.

Comment: @user1011627 unfortunately I didn't find answer yet.

Answer (score 0):

The method `setBinary()` of `ChromeOptions` is supposed to be used to set the path to the **Chrome** browser. The problem is you are using to set the path where **chromedriver** (i.e. the binary file required by Selenium WebDriver to communicate with Chrome) is downloaded by WebDriverManager. Therefore, you need to remove that line:

```
options.setBinary("/tmp");
```